# How do I query by an attribute when that attribute is an array and I'm looking for a certain value within that array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a User model, and a user has many seniors. I want to return all user records who's senior_ids column contains id= x. The best I could come up with was User.where("? IN senior_ids", x), but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you save the `array` of `senior_ids` into the table?  Am I correct in reading this that you have one row, and that row's `senior_ids` column is an array?  Is there a reason you did this instead of using a relational model like `User has_many :seniors`?

Comment: senior_ids is an array of integers.  I am using a relational model, but you also need to store the ids somewhere, do you not?

Comment: What is `senior`?  Is that it's own table/model?  Why don't you have `senior.user_id` so that the relationship works correctly?

Comment: Maybe read up on `ActiveRecord` associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible right now. I have to map already existing records from another model to the users model and set up the relational ships via code for the existing records since this is being applied to production. If I could do that I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: My suggestion?  Make a rake task that converts all your `senior_ids` arrays into a proper database primary/foreign key relationship and then fix any locations where you're assuming that array exists.  Seems like you're gonna get heaps and heaps of technical debt and end up with a pretty unmaintainable bit of code if you don't.  My 2 cents.  But I guess I don't know exactly what your circumstance is... this just feels very very wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your design is slightly wrong here. You should use has_and_belongs_to_many association (or has_many :through) to connect users and seniors. You can read about those under a link in nzifnab's comment. Then you could simply write:

```
senior.users
```

With current design you can go with:

```
User.all.select {|user| user.senior_ids.include? x}
```

however it is gona be really slow and horribly ugly. Keeping serialized array of ids is in general a very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I'm looking for. This operation will only be run once... ever, so I'm not concerned about how slow it will be. I'm trying to restructure a database that is already in production right now, so I basically need to rip everything out and then map everything to a different table and then reconnect the dots as far as relationships between different records goes. Once I'm done doing this I will then be able to say something like senior.users. This probably doesn't make any sense though, as I'm not very good at explaining myself :/